# How do Xcode's ":configuration" conditional compilation directives work in an xcconfig file?

Tags: ios, xcode

When copying a target's build settings and pasting them into an xcconfig file as plain text, one finds the output sectioned off by conditions for each build configuration, e.g.:

```
//:configuration = Debug
SETTING = value
SETTING = value
SETTING = value

//:configuration = Release
SETTING = value
SETTING = value
SETTING = value

//:completeSettings = some
SETTING
SETTING
SETTING
```

Some questions about how the ":configuration" directives are used:

1. If I specify a setting above all of them in the same file, will it apply to all build configurations?
2. I assume they apply to a *group* of settings below them, but do they apply to settings following empty lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**:

The comments are neither conditions, nor directives. **They are just comments, used to clarify what build configuration the entries that follow apply to**. When you copy the complete build settings of a target, the resulting text is not meant to be used in a single xcconfig file. Rather, it can be used to extract the elements you need for different config files. The comments make it easy to find the settings you need for a particular build configuration.

So, if you assign an xcconfig file to the Debug build configuration of a target, you can copy the settings under `//:configuration = Debug` to that file, and then make any changes there, as needed.

**Long answer**:

You can assign exactly one xcconfig file per build configuration per target.

*(You do this in the project's **Info** editor, under **Configurations**, where you'll find a list of configurations, where each configuration can be expanded to show a list comprising of the project and its targets. You can assign one config file to each of these by choosing from a list of config files. The listed config files consists of all the config files you added to the project.)*

The settings listed in an assigned xcconfig file are used in the construction of the build settings *for the target and build configuration combination it was assigned to*, and they will be reflected in the Build Settings editor in Xcode. The build system uses a hierarchy of configuration settings that is used to construct the settings that will finally be applied.

*(You can see this reflected in the Xcode Build settings editor Select **All** and **Levels** at the top of the Build Settings editor to everything.) The build system starts out with defaults for the platform (e.g. *iOS Default*). These can be changed by settings at the project level, and then by settings at the target level. The Build Settings editor finally lists the **Resolved** settings, so that you can see exactly which settings will be applied.)*

Settings are applied in the following order, where each subsequent entry will override the previous setting:

```
Default -> Project Config File -> Project -> Target Config File -> Target.
```

So, if you specify, say, a *Valid Architecture* in a config file assigned to the project for a certain build configuration, then that setting will override the default setting. However, if, in Xcode's build settings editor you specify another value for that setting at the project level, then that value will override the value specified in the xcconfig file. Next, if there is an entry in an xcconfig file for the target for that build configuration, then that value will be applied, unless of course, it is overridden by a value for that setting at the target level in the Build Settings Editor. (Confused yet? :-)

As I wrote, only a single xcconfig file can be applied per target/build-configuration combination. Fortunately xcconfig files can import other xcconfig files so that groups of settings can be combined into logical units and then imported into the final xcconfig files, that are to be assigned to a target/build-configuration.  If you want to learn more about the contents of xcconfig files take a look here:
[The Unofficial Guide to xcconfig files](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html)